Script to automate the creation of pull request and merge using GitHub Actions
I'm trying to automate the process using GitHub Actions if any push is made on the second branch or any branch excluding the main branch, compare the changes between main branch and other branch where changes made, and choose two branches to see what’s changed and start a new pull request. If any changes are identified and merge once it reviewed to main branch. But i'm not getting any error and unable to create the pull request using script and see the changes.
Here's my workflow:
name: Auto Create PR on Push to Non-Main Branch

on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - main

jobs:
  create_pull_request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Ensure full history is fetched to allow comparisons

      - name: Fetch all branches
        run: git fetch origin main

      - name: Check for differences
        id: diff_check
        run: |
          git diff --quiet origin/main || echo "has_changes=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Create Pull Request if changes detected
        if: env.has_changes == 'true'
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v5
        with:
          base: main  # The branch you want to merge into (usually 'main')
          head: ${{ github.ref_name }}  # The branch where the push occurred
          title: "Auto PR: Changes in ${{ github.ref_name }}"
          body: "This PR was automatically created by GitHub Actions because changes were pushed to the ${{ github.ref_name }} branch."
          branch-suffix: timestamp

The scenario is like in the main branch I have main.tf which has the resource group creation and another branch called test-patch-1  that has main.tf with resource group creation and storage account creation. Once I made push to to the test-patch-1 it should trigger the workflow and do the above mentioned steps.

Please add the logs of your workflow in your question.

As per docs, you need to add this to the job:
permissions:
  contents: write
  pull-requests: write

They also want the token to be passed explicitly
with:
  token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

